# Why is NAD used mainly for catabolic reactions and NADP used mainly for anabolic reactions?

Tags: biochemistry

NADH is used mainly in cellular respiration and the NAD<sup>+</sup> to NADH ratio inside the cell is kept high, but NADPH is mainly used in photosynthesis and the NADPH to NADP<sup>+</sup> ratio is kept low in animal cells.

Why is this?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NADH vs. NADPH: Where is each one used and why that instead of the other?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/801/nadh-vs-nadph-where-is-each-one-used-and-why-that-instead-of-the-other). ——— Please note that one part of the expected prior research on this site is that you look for previous questions and answers..

Comment: [1] For a very interesting perspective on a slightly different question, "why are there two almost identical cofactors (NAD and NADP) anyway?" see [Why NADP](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/096800049390033J?via%3Dihub) by B.T. Kaufman, who argues that phosphorylation on the 2'-position of the ribose may be _protective_ "from the drastic
effects of the ribosylation reactions" and other non-redox reactions that NAD is involved in. ...

Comment: [2]  He points out that (only?) NADP and DNA are modified on the 2'-position of ribose, but Coenzyme-A, cyclic-AMP and [PAPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3%27-Phosphoadenosine-5%27-phosphosulfate) are all modified at the 3'-position

Answer (score 1):

NADPH is first generated in the light reactions of photosynthesis before it is used in the reductive synthesis of sugars. But this would seem irrelevant to mammalian systems. NADPH is used in mammalian cells for reductive synthetic reactions, e.g. fatty acid and steroid synthesis.

Although it is merely an opinion, it would seem to me advantageous to separate pools of reducing power for energy generation and synthesis so as to allow regulatory prioritization of the former over the latter. And, incidentally, the generation of NADPH in mammalian cells is independent of that of NADH, being primarily in the pentose phosphate shunt, a pathway found particularly in tissues like adipose tissue, mammary gland, liver and steroid-synthesizing tissues.

Although I now see that a similar question has been [asked before](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/801/nadh-vs-nadph-where-is-each-one-used-and-why-that-instead-of-the-other) the most voted answer repeats the somewhat unsatisfactory statement of the question (to be found in Albers *et al.*):

“The ratio of NAD<sup>+</sup> to NADH inside the cell is high, while the ratio of NADP<sup>+</sup> to NADPH is kept low.”

The reason I consider this unsatisfactory is, as just stated, some tissues are specialized for reductive synthesis of fatty acids and steroids, whereas others are not. Their need for NADPH will obviously differ, as will the redox ratio. Remarks about “the cell” are unfortunately typical of texts generalizing metabolism from bacteria.

Comment: @user338907 — Yes, of course you are right. I'm afraid I always tend to focus on the actual energy generation aspects of photosynthesis (the light reactions) — the dark reactions being of less fundamental interest to me. I'll correct my answer.